# Nest Thermostat E power error

Tags: hvac

I just picked up a supposedly-NIB Nest Thermostat E.  Just messing around with it before I install it, I applied 24vac (using a wall wart) to its R and C terminals.   It lets me go through a lot of the setup stuff (connect to wifi, set location, etc) but then gives an E194 error "no power wire detected, R wire required".

Is there something wrong with the thermostat, or is it simply confused because there is nothing connected to any of the other terminals ?   If I understand thermostat wiring correctly, R and C should power the thing up.

FOLLOWUP: It was suggested below that the base (which has the push terminals for the thermostat wires and a tiny connector that the display plugs into) was faulty.  So I used my DVM to check for continuity between both the C and the R terminals to any of the pins in the display connector.   Nada.   So I took the cover off the back of the base.  It's not just providing continuity.   There's a bunch of circuitry there, including various SOICs.

Comment: Some words are worth a thousand pix :-). Thing is sitting on my bench.   The two wires from a 24vac wall wart are attached to the R and C terminals on the thermostat.   Nothing is attached to the other terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a dope.  The instructions for the thermostat state clearly that it is not compatible with stranded wires.   I assumed that was just a simple way of ruling out incompatible systems, since 24vac thermostats are invariably wired with solid 18awg wire. On my bench hookup, I used the stranded wires coming out of the 24vac wall wart.  Evidently they weren't connecting properly (into the spring terminals in the Nest thermostat base), hence the error message about no power.  I knew I was on to something when I inserted solid wires and the spring levers did not return to their original position, the way they did with the stranded wires.  It still seems odd, since the stranded wires were firmly gripped - they resisted pulling out.